# Prompt Asking For Password When Pressing A Button

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to add a prompt everytime someone tries to press the button to 'Delete' or 'Download' a file (in my project, you can upload files with passwords, so that if someone wants to delete/download the file, he needs to enter a password).

The password itself is saved in the models.py using django - how would i be able to to so in my code (listing my viwes.py to the html code, urls.py, models.py, forms.py, HTML CODE Itself).

```
    @login_required(login_url='login')
def My_Files(request):
    files = File.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home/My Files.html', {"files" : files})






    path("MyFiles", views.My_Files, name="my_files"),
    path("MyFiles/<int:pk>/", views.delete_file, name="delete_file"),










{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} {% endblock title %}

<!-- Specific CSS goes HERE -->
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block content %}
      {% include "includes/footer.html" %}
<h2>My Files</h2>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>File Description</th>
        <th>Uploaded By</th>
        <th>Download</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for file in files %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ file.File_Name }}</td>
        <td> {{ file.File_Type }}</td>
        <td> {{ file.Uploaded_By }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ file.File.url }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" target="_blank">
               Download File
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_file' file.pk %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dange btn-sm">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock content %}

<!-- Specific JS goes HERE --> 
{% block javascripts %}

  <script>

            }
          },
        },
      },
    });
  </script>

{% endblock javascripts %}






class File(models.Model):
File_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
File_Type = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
Uploaded_By = models.CharField(max_length=90,default=None,blank=True, null=True)
Password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
File = models.FileField(upload_to='Files')

def __str__(self):
    return self.File_Name

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.File.delete()
    super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

def UploadedBy(self,username):
    self.File.Uploaded_By = username







 # Create your forms here.

class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= File
        fields= ["File_Name", "File_Type","Uploaded_By","Password","File"]
```

Comment: You should include your download and delete views to the question. Also, in your ```uploadedby``` method in your ```File``` model you call ```username``` but there is no argument called ```username``` in the scope of the file object.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a form with a field for entering password which validates against the password of the specific file, then add your delete or download logic after form.is_valid() is called